# Laravel passing variable from multiple models

Tags: laravel-5

I have 2 models
  User
  Customer

Each user hasMany customers (aka Accounts)

the user model has

```
public function customer() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Customer', 'id','customer_id');
}
```

but when i try to output this:

```
$user->customer->name
```

i get an error saying:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name
```

When i use this one, i get the entire customers record output in JSON.

```
$user->customer
```

So the relationship is working, but obviously i am missing something. I was sure this was the right way to do it. I swear this worked in Laravel4.2 but now that I'm in Laravel 5 it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error and the below link says, It is returning a collection (hasMany) not a single object, you need to either loop over the collection or do direct access in the collection based on the index.

that is to say... does doing this work?..

```
$user->customer[0]->name
```

http://laravel.io/forum/04-10-2014-undefined-property-illuminatedatabaseeloquentcollectionitem

Comment: Thanks! i knew this was easy, id just been looking at this for too long... That was exactly what i was doing wrong.. guess i should pay more attention to my errors... didn't even notice it was returning a collection

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over customers, if you want display customers in laravel view you can do the following

```
       @foreach
              ($user->customer as  $cust)
              {{$cust->name}}
       @endforeach
```